# Mongoose - How to automatically add filter to each query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to implement some kind of security scoping mechanism for our customers data in MongoDB. We are currently using mongoose ORM for models and executing queries.

Every collection in DB has `accountId` field, so I want to modify every query that executed through mongoose, and add filter `{ $and: [{existing filter}, {accountId: { $in:[list of accounts allowed to this user] }}] }`.

We already have many queries and the purpose is to create general solution that will affect existing queries and every new query that will be written.

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and Mongoose, and I don't really know how I can make it in mongoose. I saw it support plugins, but not sure if this will allow me to do what I need. 
I also saw some solutions that makes monkey patch on `mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions`, but I not really understand how I can utilize this solution for my needs.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a mongoose expert myself by any means but I'm reading https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete/blob/master/index.js#L102 which seems to be a plugin and is overriding those methods so I guess you can base a plugin off of that

Comment: @apokryfos Trying to look on it and figure out what and how it does. Thanks for direction to look on.